# How to install .apk on Alpine Linux like .deb in Debian using dpkg

Tags: linux, installation

My question is in the title. Problem:

[Comparison with other distros](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Comparison_with_other_distros) doesn't speak about installing a local .deb in Debian or whatever is Gentoo's equivalent or Alpine Linux's .apk. Plus the command `apk add` complains about unsatisfiable dependencies for the world when I want it to install from .apk file downloaded, and it doesn't tell what's wrong, just:

```
world: <package_name> <package_name>
```

Simple more-or-less obvious searches such as `how to install apk on alpine linux` returns something weird or Android stuff, making Alpine Linux look like it doesn't exist in the first place -or- doesn't support installing a downloaded package like you can do in Debian with dpkg.

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you are trying to install glibc in Alpine

Download the packages into your current directory

```
wget "https://circle-artifacts.com/gh/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/6/artifacts/0/home/ubuntu/alpine-pkg-glibc/packages/x86_64/glibc-2.21-r2.apk"
wget "https://circle-artifacts.com/gh/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/6/artifacts/0/home/ubuntu/alpine-pkg-glibc/packages/x86_64/glibc-bin-2.21-r2.apk"
```

Then, use apk with `--allow-untrusted` flag

```
apk add --allow-untrusted glibc-2.21-r2.apk glibc-bin-2.21-r2.apk
```

And finish the installation (only needed in this example)

```
/usr/glibc/usr/bin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc/usr/lib
```

Comment: how do I open the archive?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, prebuilt packages are preferrable, but if you want or don't mind building from source, you can do it this way:

`a.sh`:

```sh
apk add alpine-sdk sudo
abuild-keygen -ain
git clone --branch v3.15.4 --single-branch --depth 1 https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports
cd aports/main/musl
abuild -rF
apk add /root/packages/main/x86_64/musl-1.2.2-r7.apk
```

```
$ docker run --rm -itv $PWD:/host alpine:3.15 sh -eux host/a.sh
```

If you're doing it on the host OS, you generally don't want to build under `root`. In which case you don't need to pass `-F` to `abuild`.

For further details you can refer to [this page](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Include:Abuild).

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [AlpineLinux Wiki](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Main_Page) page on [**Alpine Linux package management**](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management)?

Verbatim from there,

> Because Alpine Linux is designed to run from RAM, package management involves two phases:
>
> 1. Installing / Upgrading / Deleting packages on a running system
> 2. Restoring a system to a previously configured state (e.g. after reboot), including all previously installed packages and locally modified configuration files. (RAM-Based Installs Only)
>
> **apk** is the tool used to install, upgrade, or delete software on a running sytem.
>   **lbu** is the tool used to capture the data necessary to restore a system to a previously configured state.
>
> This page documents the [apk tool](http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/apk-tools.git) - See the [Alpine Local Backup page](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup) for the lbu tool.

Comment: This does not answer the question.